# wxPython: how to lay one panel over another

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, panel, sizer

This is about wxPython.

I would like to have 2 Panels laying one over the other:
`PanelBG` should be some sort of a "background", with its own GridBagSizer with subPanels, StaticTexts and so on;
`PanelFG` should be the "foreground" panel, also with its own GridBagSizer with some StaticTexts, Buttons... but a transparent background, in such a way that `PanelBG` is visible wherever `PanelFG` doesn't lay widgets.

I need both Panels to stretch to all the sides of the frame, even when resizing the window, though never changing the reciprocal proportions, that's why I'm not sure if there's a way to use absolute positioning.

In case you are wondering, the reason why I don't want to use a single Panel is that merging the 2 GridBoxSizers would require me to place many many more cells in the sizer, because rows and columns of foreground and background don't always coincide, and I should split them in many cells, with grid dimensions growing up to hundreds**2.
Since the content I want to put in the foreground needs to be updated and refreshed quite often, this would require redrawing all the cells every time, which would take 10 - 20 seconds to complete the operation (tested). Updating only the foreground would require just some hundredths of a second instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you create another sizer that is split in two, and put the two sizers in one each?

Comment: Oh man, I'm totally trying it! I really didn't think of that possibility, I'll tell you if I can make it work

Comment: Wait wait, how do you make the two child sizers overlap? If I use a BoxSizer they will still be stacking vertically or horizontally... Can you point me to an example of what you are saying?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a very hard time understanding what your goal is. The two grids supposed to be z-plane above each other? and they don't always line up? I can't imagine how that wouldn't be exceptionally confusing to use for a user. Can you give a drawing or more explanation of the end result?

Comment: Exactly, z-plane above each other. The application is a calendar showing events in a day: the background shows the o'clock hours as labels on the left and to the right side it displays coloured horizontal lines showing 15-minute gaps. The foreground shows the event rectangles, which can span horizontally depending on how many other events are happening at the same time, and vertically depending on the duration of the event itself. It's a calendar like there are many around in other applications, however I'll try to provide some graphical representation of this thing.

Comment: Ahh, that makes it much easier to visualize. It sounds like you might need some kind of absolute positioning on your foreground objects with z-depth, but I haven't done anything like that in wx. I would probably update your question with more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much TorelTwiddler! However I was thinking: what if I managed to draw the background horizontal lines with a background bitmap? Sounds easier to you?

Comment: That would probably be easier to draw on, but you'd then run into the issue of changing weeks/months, and generating those images. If you're not limited to python, you may be able to find pre-made calendar widgets that do everything you need in, say, flash.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this guide: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/ At the moment I'm limited to Python, I've managed to develop all the backend code by myself, I won't throw it away just because I can't get the frontend working! :D

Comment: Adding another, maybe better method: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/128350/1119379#post1119379 I hope this will lead me to learn in the future even how to generate the image dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be at least partially a change of direction, but it might be worth examining what other rendering options you have.

In particular, I'm thinking of wxWebKit (http://wxwebkit.kosoftworks.com/), which would let you do layering, etc. using the WebKit browser rendering engine. I'm not sure whether it's at a stage that would provide everything you need since I haven't actually used it, but even if it doesn't work then it may be an approach worth trying - using HTML/CSS for part of your display, while wrapping the whole in a wxPython app.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know of that project, it would be really great to be able to use HTML/CSS for this kind of job! However I'm developing on Linux and it seems I should manage to build it by myself, so at the moment I'm going to use dynamic background bitmaps as a workaround, but I will surely keep an eye on wxWebkit and probably rewrite my calendar that way once I get a grasp of it. Thank you, this is probably going to be my accepted answer :)

Comment: I originally looked at the HTML options in stock wxPython, but was unimpressed. I've been thinking in that direction ever since I first looked at the layout possibilities for Java development and was reminded of looking at the raw files of Visual Basic many years ago. Sure, I can build a UI in code, but why would I want to when there are better display options?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is a calendar with rectangles for the days containing the events for the days.

The simple thing would be to use a wxGrid, with seven columns and four or five rows, to represent the months.  You would then place the events into the grid cell for the correct date.  The wxGrid widget would look after the details of refreshing everything properly.

Using wxGrid you might lose a little control over the exact appearance, though wxGrid is very flexible and feature rich once you learn its many methods, but you would save yourself having to write large amounts of code that would require significant effort to debug.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I took a look at wxGrid before starting this project, but it doesn't provide the ability to overlay panels or sizers, and that's what I'm looking for. At the moment I think I've found a workaround using dynamic background bitmaps, see the comments under the question

Comment: IMHO you do not need to muck around with overlays or sizers if you use wxGrid.

Comment: The problem is that if I do what I want all in the same "plane" I have to do too many controls and cell divisions in order to make the fg and the bg fit together. In the backend I come up with two dictionaries, one for the fg, the other for the bg, and to make the long story short, they define how their items are laid in the respective grids. Combining the two kinds of items would be like, say, computing how to draw 3 rectangles on a striped background: if you want to put all on the same plane you have to calculate where to "cut" the stripes and create the "holes" for the rectangles.